# Why can't I access useAsyncData in a Nuxt 3 script setup tag for an if-statement?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using the Prismic API to get some data that I want to show in my Nuxt3 template.
Everything works fine, I just want to show a 404 page when there is no data instead of a 500 error. I have added a check if the data is empty:

```html
<script setup>
    const route = useRoute()
    const name = route.params.werke;
    const { client } = usePrismic()
    const { data: werk } = await useAsyncData('werk', () => client.getByUID("werk", name))
    if (!werk.uid) {
     throw createError({ statusCode: 404, statusMessage: 'Page Not Found' })
    }

</script>
```

The problem is, that at the `if (!werk.uid)` part werk.uid is ALWAYS empty. So I always get that 404 error. In my template werk.uid is not empty so I assume there is a problem, where the if statement can't access the const variable with useAsyncData?

Any ideas? The official Docs recommend it in a similar way to me: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/error-handling/#example-1

Comment: Not sure at all, but maybe try that one `async () => await client.getByUID("werk", name)`?

Comment: I tried that and it couldn't fetch anything. Maybe prismic needs the useAsyncData? https://v3.prismic.nuxtjs.org/guides/basics/fetching-content

Comment: Not sure if her DMs are open, but maybe send her something: https://twitter.com/li_hbr

Comment: did you try to access werk.value? werk.value.uid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone in the prismic forum helped me to find the solution. It is a Vue 3 specific problem:

You'll need to use .value after werk: `(!werk.value)`. Instead of just `(werk.anything)`

Comment: Not a Vue problem, but characteristic.